# Reading from file in C++, dealing with blanks

Tags: c++, string, file, integer, ifstream

I am tying to read from a text file in C++98. It has a pattern, but sometimes a field is empty:

```
ID Name Grade level  
1 a 80 A
2 b    B
3 c 90 A
```

How can I read from file such that I can ignore the blanks?
( I wish  I could simply use Regex: \d*)

Is there any simple way of doing that?

Comment: Are the fields guaranteed to be fixed-width?

Comment: If you want to treat them as string, No! they can be small or large numbers

Comment: Then how can you tell which field is missing on line 2? Are fields always separated by a single space?

Comment: C++11 has a regular expressions library. - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: Thank you. But the system does not support C++11. I was thinking about using the "system()", but there should an easier way.

Comment: boost regex.... http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html

Comment: By "ignore the blanks" do you mean ignore lines that have blank fields or recover from having an empty field and fill it with a default value?

Comment: If a field is missing, you need to determine which field it was by checking the content of the existing fields. e.g. if the third term has letters in it, the Grade was skipped.

Comment: @MorphingDragon, I mean the 2nd: Recover and fill it with a default value.

Comment: @mukunda: you mean using a try-catch or something?

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism You just need to count how many terms are in the line, if there's less than 4 then you know something is missing. If there is just one field missing, then you can deduce which field it is by checking the terms against the pattern you have (number,letters,number,letters)

Comment: @mukunda, yes, but how? What should I read? (number, letter, number/null?, letter)? how to count? The number of whitespaces are not fixed.

Comment: I think try-catch would work. right? try{read-an-int} catch{set it to default; convert what you have read to string}. would it work? let me try.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use what knowledge you have about the input to make assumptions about what is missing. You can use `std::stringstream` to parse individual terms from a text line. In other words `std::stringstream` *deals with blanks* by ignoring spaces and getting a complete term only, for example `std::stringstream("aaa      bbb") >> a >> b` will load strings `a` with `"aaa"` and `b` with `"bbb"`.

Here is an example program that parses the input, making a robust parser from scratch can be difficult, but if your input is strict and you know exactly what to expect then you can get away with some simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// holds a data entry
struct Entry {
    int id;
    std::string name;
    int grade;
    std::string level;

    Entry() {
        // default values, if they are missing.
        id = 0;
        name = "Unknown";
        grade = 0;
        level = "?";
    }

    void ParseFromStream( std::stringstream &line ) {

        std::string s;
        line >> s;

        if( s[0] >= '0' && s[0] <= '9' ) {
            // a number, this is the ID.
            id = atoi( s.c_str() );

            // get next term
            if( line.eof() ) return;
            line >> s;
        }

        if( s[0] >= 'a' && s[0] <= 'z' || s[0] >= 'A' && s[0] <= 'Z' ) {
            // a letter, this is the name
            name = s;

            // get next term
            if( line.eof() ) return;
            line >> s; 
        }

        if( s[0] >= '0' && s[0] <= '9' ) {
            // a number, this is the grade
            grade = atoi( s.c_str() );

            // get next term
            if( line.eof() ) return;
            line >> s; 
        }

        // last term, must be level
        level = s;
    } 
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(void)
{
    std::ifstream input( "test.txt" );

    std::string line;
    std::getline( input, line ); // (ignore text header)

    while( !input.eof() ) {
        Entry entry;

        std::getline( input, line ); // skip header
        if( line == "" ) continue; // skip empty lines.

        entry.ParseFromStream( std::stringstream( line ));

        std::cout << entry.id << ' ' << entry.name << ' ' << 
                     entry.grade << ' ' << entry.level << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```